# Access local server from outside without port forwarding

Tags: ssh, port, router, owncloud, ssh-tunnel

I am in a situation where I can't change the port forwarding rules of my router, and I would like to use a service like own cloud. I have a server with a fixed IP to which I can make a SSH tunnel. My two questions are:

By doing an ssh tunnel, all the data is transmitted through the server? (If there's a limit to the transfer rate at my server side it would be a problem).

Is there another way to circumvent the port forwarding on the router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to forward an SSH port also. I'd be surprised if that was allowed by default on a router.

---

> By doing an ssh tunnel, all the data is transmitted through the server?

Yes. An SSH tunnel is the "poor-man's VPN".

---

> ”I want to expose a local server behind a NAT or firewall to the internet.”
>
> `ngrok` allows you to expose a ... server running on your local machine to the internet. Just tell `ngrok` what port your ... server is listening on

`ngrok http <http_port>`

or

`ngrok tcp <tcp_port>`

-- [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

---

An SSH tunnel would be **more secure**.

Comment: To my understanding ngrok is like an SSH tunnel but just outsourcing it.

Comment: It doesn't create an encrypted tunnel (by default), so not exactly. It's open source, if you want to look at it. https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok